# Unable to give write permissions to Docker volume to non-root user in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, permissions, docker-volume

I'm running a Docker Compose environment in which to execute a bunch of Selenium tests. In order to do that, I'm using the [images Selenium provides](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium). I run two containers: one as the **Selenium HUB** and another as a **Selenium Firefox Node**. I have a third container defined who is in charge of the tests execution (let's call it **Tests Node**).

I created a Docker volume used by the **Selenium Firefox Node** and the **Tests Node** so certain files can be shared by them both. I called the volume `selenium_volume` and it's mounted for both on `/selenium_tests`.

I soon faced a problem for that folder is created in both systems for user `root`, but the user the **Selenium Firefox Node** uses by default is `seluser`. It has read but not write permissions, which I need.

I tried to use the following as the container `entrypoint`, so I make `seluser` the owner of the directory: `bash -c 'sudo chown -R seluser:seluser /selenium_tests && /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'`, but it's not working.

When I connect to the container after it's launched (`docker exec -ti selenium-firefox bash`), I see the folder still belongs to `root`. If I then once connected run the command `sudo chown -R seluser:seluser /selenium_tests && /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'`, the folder permissions are changed and we reach to the point I was expecting.

I would like to know why it's working when I run the command manually but it's not when running through the `entrypoint` before the entrypoint script of the container.

Currently my `docker-compose.yml` looks similar to the following:

```yaml
    version: '3.8'
    
    services:
      tests-node:
        build: .
        depends_on:
         - selenium-hub
         - selenium-firefox
        # the wait-for-it.sh command makes the container wait until the Selenium containers are ready to work
        entrypoint: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "-t", "15", "selenium-firefox:5555", "--"]
        command: ["execute_tests.sh"]
        volumes:
          - ./remote_reports/:/selenium_tests/reports/
          - type: volume
            source: selenium_volume
            target: /selenium_tests
        networks:
          selenium_net: {}
    
      selenium-hub:
        image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
        ports:
          - "4444:4444"
        networks:
          selenium_net: {}
    
      selenium-firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        entrypoint: bash -c 'sudo chown -R seluser:seluser /selenium_tests && /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
        volumes:
          - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
          - type: volume
            source: selenium_volume
            target: /selenium_tests
        environment:
          - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
          - HUB_PORT=4444
        networks:
          selenium_net: {}
        expose:
          - 5555
    
    volumes:
      selenium_volume:
    
    networks:
      selenium_net:
        driver: bridge
```

I tried to run the chown command as `command` after the `entrypoint` but it never reaches I think because the script that is launched during the `entrypoint` keeps running in foreground.

I would like to do all the things directly on the docker-compose.yml and avoiding to create any Dockerfile, but I don't know if this is possible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution. Using this as the entrypoint:

```
bash -c '( while ! timeout 1 bash -c "echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/5555"; do sleep 1; done ; sudo chown -R seluser:seluser /selenium_tests ) & /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
```

It runs the part of the code before the `&` in background, allowing `entry_point.sh` to run without a problem. When the port 5555 is ready, it finally gives the permissions to the desired folder to `seluser`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add `chmod -R 777 /selenium_tests` to `execute_tests.sh` before starting the tests. In this case, @aorestr, you don't need to change `entrypoint` of the `selenium-firefox` container.