# RSelenium and Docker on remote Linux server - cannot download files

Tags: r, docker, rselenium

I'm trying to run an R script that uses RSelenium to scrape a website and download a file.

I've managed to do this on my local machine just fine.

I've been struggling however to do the same on a remote Linux server.

- More specifically, the file doesn't want to download (the rest of the code works fine though).
- I've went through this potential duplicate question - but it didn't solve my problem ([Unable to give write permissions to Docker volume to non-root user in Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191953/unable-to-give-write-permissions-to-docker-volume-to-non-root-user-in-docker-com))

Code:

```
# To start up Docker Container
system('sudo docker run -d --rm --name selenium_container -v /home/Downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads -p 4445:4444 -p 5900:5900 selenium/standalone-chrome:3.14')

# To initiate driver in R "x.x.x.x" being the server IP address (have used 'localhost' as well.
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "x.x.x.x", 
                                 port = 4445L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
```

Expected result from clicking on download button:

File should download to /home/Downloads and also be in docker container in /home/seluser/Downloads

Actual result:

No files in those folders.

Expected problem:

Read/Write permissions of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue:

It was a Read/Write permissions issue.

Fixed it with:
`chmod 777 -R /Downloads/Location`